# Converting data to list

Tags: python

I have to convert this data to two lists of dictionaries present in them. The two lists being buydata and selldata. How can I do that and what is the type of depth variable.

```
'depth': {'buy': [{'orders': 1, 'price': 474.95, 'quantity': 1},
                   {'orders': 3, 'price': 474.9, 'quantity': 3},
                   {'orders': 1, 'price': 474.85, 'quantity': 2},
                   {'orders': 2, 'price': 474.7, 'quantity': 4}],
           'sell': [{'orders': 5, 'price': 475.1, 'quantity': 7},
                    {'orders': 2, 'price': 475.15, 'quantity': 2},
                    {'orders': 6, 'price': 475.2, 'quantity': 19},
                    {'orders': 4, 'price': 475.25, 'quantity': 4},
                    {'orders': 6, 'price': 475.3, 'quantity': 10}]}
```

Comment: `buy, sell = json["buy"], json["sell"]`

Comment: Im a little in doubth as to what you want out and how it would look. Could you provide an expected outcome? Is it just the list of dicts under each 'buy' and 'sell' you want returned as lists of dicts or is it a different format?

Comment: Also why you want to store it in 2 variable..? I don't see any befit in that,

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
a = {'depth': {'buy': [{'orders': 1, 'price': 474.95, 'quantity': 1},
                   {'orders': 3, 'price': 474.9, 'quantity': 3},
                   {'orders': 1, 'price': 474.85, 'quantity': 2},
                   {'orders': 2, 'price': 474.7, 'quantity': 4}],
           'sell': [{'orders': 5, 'price': 475.1, 'quantity': 7},
                    {'orders': 2, 'price': 475.15, 'quantity': 2},
                    {'orders': 6, 'price': 475.2, 'quantity': 19},
                    {'orders': 4, 'price': 475.25, 'quantity': 4},
                    {'orders': 6, 'price': 475.3, 'quantity': 10}]}}

buy, sell = a['depth']['buy'], a['depth']['sell']
```